# Installing Npgsql.dll for Postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, postgresql, npgsql

So I am having an issue installing npgsql.dll and mono.security.dll. I've been trying to figure this out for so long... please help. Here are the steps I've done...

1. Download zip file from https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql
2. Go into Visual Studio and start new project. C# Command (not sure which specific project I was supposed to create)
3. Create a strong key name
4. Then I try to install the .dll files using gacutil

In the zip file I've downloaded in step 1, I cannot find Npgsql.dll and Mono.Security.dll anywhere...

I've also tried downloading other zip files that have actually had those files, however, when I try to install them in command (gacutil /i C:...\Npgsql.dll) I just keep getting the following error:

> "Failure adding assembly to cache: ???????????"

Comment: You downloaded the source code not the dll.You need to open `Npgsql-dnx.sln` in VS and just build the project the dll will be created in debug folder

Comment: or go to http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140 and download npsql dll for your .net framework

Comment: I opened Npgsql-dnx, but it says it is unsupported. I then tried another source code (npgsql-3.0.2, the most recent) and it says "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly"

Comment: @wingedpanther this is my first time really using VS

Comment: Follow my second comment,You will get _dll_ directly from that link

Comment: @wingedpanther I don't know what I'm doing wrong here... I downloaded the zip file for my .net framework (4.5), started a new project, created a strong key name, and then tried to install with gacutil... But still getting the same "Failure adding assembly to cache: ?????????"

Comment: Add DLL as project reference just by right click _project name_ in _solution explorer_ and select  _add reference_ and choose `npgsql dll`

Comment: Can't you just add it using NuGet?

Comment: @wingedpanther Thank you so much. I finally got it done, at least I think...  I added the new entry code in machine.config and saved. That should be it right??

Comment: Unless you have a *very* good reason for doing so, you really shouldn't install Npgsql in the GAC or even build it yourself. as @Kamo suggests Npgsql is best installed via nuget like any other .NET package.

Comment: Try this `gacutil.exe -i Npgsql.dll`

Answer (score 11):

In Visual Studio 2017, go to menu Tools-> NuGet Package Manager-> Package Manager Console.
Run command:

`Install-Package Npgsql -Version 3.2.7`

To unstall version 3.2.7... and so on...

More versions are available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/

Answer (score 4):

you can use installation project :  https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases

download MSI package

Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to obtain the npgsql.dll file is:

1. Open Visual Studio and start a new project -- ASP.NET Core for instance.
2. Use the NuGet Package Manager to install Postgres packages
3. Open a command prompt and cd to your user directory: 'cd \users\
4. Look for the dll: 'dir /s/p npgsql.dll'

The dll will be in your project directory. You will also find the dll in the .nuget package directory.