# Connect to postgresql database error could not load file or assembly Mono.Security

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

When connecting to the database I get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Security, Version=4.0.0.0. Culture=neutral PublicKeyToken ...

And the error is targeted the connection string line.

Comment: With some code lines it would help

Comment: Guess is: [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org) has a dependency on `Mono.Security`, and this dependency is not met. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643960/installing-npgsql-dll-for-postgresql, and speciy which verson of NpgSQL you're using.

Comment: Its working now. I download this: http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/3797/Setup_Npgsql-2.2.3.0-r2-net45.exe